# Lsode package installation in octave

Tags: package, octave, equivalence, octave-gui

I have octave version 6.3. I don't have lsode package in-built. From which repository, i can install it in octave?

My second question:
Sometimes to help describe one expression, another expression is shown that produces identical results. The exact equivalence of expressions is indicated with ‘ ≡’.

For example: rot90 ([1, 2; 3, 4], -1) ≡ rot90 ([1, 2; 3, 4], 3) ≡ rot90 ([1, 2; 3, 4], 7)

What is the meaning of 'rot90;?

What is the meaning of this example?

How to write equivalence relation in octave?

How does all of the above expressions have equivalence relation?

Comment: The `lsode` command is generally part of base octave. Which version of octave do you have installed? Which operating system? How did you install octave in this operating system? As for the second question, `rot90` is simply an octave function (here's its manual entry: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Rearranging-Matrices.html#XREFrot90). There's no "equivalence relation" per se; whoever wrote the notes you're quoting from simply meant that rot( X, 3) and rot( X, 7) will always produce the same result (since if you rotate 4 times by 90 degress you'll always get back the original array).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou, How to write equivalence symbol in octave? You said correctly Lsode is a built-in function in my octave version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'how to write the symbol'. The `≡` symbol is not valid octave source code (except when used in strings. If you're asking if the octave interpreter has a shortcut for typing that symbol, like, e.g. the julia interpreter does, the the answer is no. Just copy it your 'character map' application, or from something like https://shapecatcher.com/